# Retrieving info from a plist

Tags: iphone, ios, plist

Small question. My plist looks like:
[image: plist]

On the screen there are two buttons (A, B) that trigger a detail view.  I'm trying to check which choice the user makes like so:

```
if ([self.question.answers objectAtIndex:0])//answer A?
    {
       //do some stuff
    }
    else if ([self.question.answers objectAtIndex:1])//Answer B?
    {
       //do some other stuff
    }
```

Any insight into why this doesn't work or a better way to make the distinction would be great! Currently both button A and B display the view controller for button A... 
Thanks!

Comment: Ik weet niet of ik je vraag wel begrijp. Not sure I understand your question. Are you asking how to check whether button A or B has tapped?

Comment: Ja dat klopt :). But this check is done in the detail view controller, so I am not accessing the buttons directly...which is why I'm trying to get which answer is pressed from the plist.

Comment: Hi pigeonfactory, in what way doesn't it work? Does that code throw an error when you tap one of the buttons?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605310/a-question-on-how-to-get-data-from-plist-how-should-it-be-layout

Comment: No, there is something wrong with the objectAtIndex I think...current both buttons trigger what is in the first if statement. So it never gets to the second one.

Comment: thanks @Praveen-K, I guess the title is a bit misleading...I am successfully getting data from the plist, just when trying to get one specific piece I'm failing.

Comment: Your if statement just tests if there is an object at index 0 which is always true when looking at the plist you posted.

Comment: hmm, I figured as much. Being new to programming I'm not sure how to solve this one. Something like: if `([[[self.question.answers objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"extra"] isEqualToString:@"bad"])` ?

Comment: Something along those lines, yes, but it's hard to say exactly because it's not clear how exactly you're loading data from the plist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current if statement is equivalent to this:

```
if ([self.question.answers objectAtIndex:0] != nil)//answer A?
{
   //do some stuff
}
else if ([self.question.answers objectAtIndex:1] != nil)//Answer B?
{
   //do some other stuff
}
```

This will always take the first branch as long as your `answers` array has a first object.

When the user taps Button A or B the corresponding answer should be assigned as a property to your detail view controller. Then inside the detail view controller you can check with something like this, where `selectedAnswer` is the property of your detail view controller:

```
if (self.selectedAnswer == [self.question.answers objectAtIndex:0])//answer A?
{
   //do some stuff
}
else if (self.selectedAnswer == [self.question.answers objectAtIndex:1])//Answer B?
{
   //do some other stuff
}
```