# obj-c append plist

Tags: objective-c

So I'm new to all this iOS stuff, and I've got somewhat of a question on appending items to a plist. My plist looks as follows;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>team</key>
    <string>red</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Guy1</string>
  </dict>
  <dict>
    <key>team</key>
    <string>blue</string>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Guy2</string>
  </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

I've already got a proper tableview set up that reads this information, so I really dont plan on changing the plist.

What I currently have set up is identical the first answer shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605310/1617071#1617071). I can get my code to compile, but nothing at all is modified (when I attempt to append). What all would I need to change to make it append specifically to the above plist.

Comment: The code in the answer you linked already allows you to add to the plist and write back out to a file. Please be more specific about what you need to know.

Comment: The method did work for me when using on a test arbitrary plist, but not on the one I have built. The plist doesn't modify at all, I know I need to change a few things to that in order for it to work, I am just unsure of what to change is all. Thanks

Comment: Your plist has an array at top level, rather than a dictionary. Use `NSMutableArray` instead of `NSMutableDictionary`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's possible to manipulate the XML stored in a property list, it's almost always easier in Objective-C to load the property list, manipulate the objects stored therein, and then save the objects back to a property list. By doing that you avoid any possibility of creating an invalid file, and the code is also much simpler.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:pathToMyPropertyList];
NSDictionary *newTeam = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"green", @"team", @"Guy4", @"name", nil];
[array addObject:newTeam]
[array writeToFile:somePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: I like simple things like this, make learning a bit easier. just one question, I get this;    'NSMutableArray' may not respond to '-appendObject:'

Comment: Sorry -- should be `-addObject:`. When all else fails, read the instructions.