# Modify an existing file in directory, with ought replacing it (iPhone)

Tags: ios, xcode, json

in my app, every time a user creates a new group, this code is created (JSON):

```
{"group a":"0864797073"}
```

...Then the code is saved in the directory in a file called groups.txt

...But when the user creates another group, I would like the file to be modified in this way:

```
{"group a":"0864797073"} 
{"group b":"0864797073"}
```

...and then...

```
{"group a":"0864797073"} 
{"group b":"0864797073"} 
{"group c":"0864797073"}
```

...so adding a new line, not replacing the file.

How can I do this??

Thanks in advance for the help.

EDIT 2:

NSString *destDir = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Apps/Quick Homework & business/%@/", namegroup.text];

```
    NSString *filename5 = namegroup.text;
    NSString *filename6 = @"group";


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *groupPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", filename6]];

    NSMutableArray *titles = [NSMutableArray array];
    [titles addObject:filename5];

    NSMutableArray *keys = [NSMutableArray array];
    [keys addObject:filename6];

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:titles forKeys:keys];

    NSString *jsonString = [dict JSONRepresentation];
    NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSFileHandle *myHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:groupPath];
    [myHandle seekToEndOfFile];
    [myHandle writeData:jsonData];
    [myHandle closeFile];

    [jsonData writeToFile: groupPath atomically: YES];

    [[self restClient] uploadFile:filename6 toPath:destDir
                    withParentRev:nil fromPath:groupPath];
```

Comment: Post the code you use to write to the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to add a line to the end of an existing file, you could use the following code.

```
NSData *newGroupData = [newGroupString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSFileHandle *myHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:filePath];
[myHandle seekToEndOfFile];
[myHandle writeData:newGroupData];
[myHandle closeFile];
```

It will up to you to set the values for `newGroupString` and `filePath`

Comment: as you can see from above, I have added your code, but still the line is not added. Actually, from the simulator folders, I have noticed that the file is deleted, and re added. How can I stop this?

Comment: Try removing the line `[jsonData writeToFile: groupPath atomically: YES];`, it's overwriting the contents after you add the line to the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

You do the following

- Read the content of the old file
- Append your new line to the read content, so now you have a collection that contains the old file + the new line the user added
- write the collection to the file, this will write all of the old contents + the new line

Comment: does this mean I have to parse the old file, and add the new and old NSDictionary? Is there a faster way?

Comment: Why would you need a faster way, if your app does not write to a big file or process very long loops then this would not be a big issue, btw there are faster ways, but not as simple as this one

Comment: Please read the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586529/how-do-i-append-a-new-item-to-a-plist